# How do I connect prints with scripts in roblox?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I need to get wait commands be executed by print. How do I do it?

```
while true do
    wait(color.Parent.Time.Value == 0)
    if not parent.BrickColor == color then
        Hide()
    end
    wait(not color.Parent.Time.Value == 0)
    Show()
    parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Random()
end
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what you mean by "executed by print"? Do you want those `wait()` commands to only happen if the condition inside them is true? Or do you want the value passed in to also be printed out to the console? Or something else?

Comment: I need to ''stop'' command to stop when the string it wants is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `repeat wait() until ...`

```
while true do
    repeat wait() until color.Parent.Time.Value == 0
    if not parent.BrickColor == color then
        Hide()
    end
    repeat wait() until not color.Parent.Time.Value == 0
    Show()
    parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Random()
end
```

Using that is fine for prototyping or early dev builds but you should try and avoid it for production code, have a look at alternatives here https://devforum.roblox.com/t/avoiding-wait-and-why/244015